# High traffic MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, configuration

I am looking for some help to twich my MYSQL server.
I am running a 5.7 MYSQL server on a 64 GB high end processor server (nothing else on it) and I just am unable to set the config for it to use all available ressouces.

So first off, I know I should soon replicate the server and have Slave/master Mysql - ill do it as soon as I exploit my first server fully. I also spent weeks in optimizing the queries and different caching (apache side) to limit the amount of queries. Now I need to make some config for it to be nice.

The situation; I have a huge amount of traffic and a huge amount of queries - and mysql seems not to be able to handle it anymore. I currently run at around 700 Selects/second (only 20 Updates and 30 Inserts) (My website and apache runs at 3k simultaneous connections). 
My first thought was MaxClients that I took up to 250; I however noticed that I never have over 7 simultaneous "Connections" (says MysqlWorkbench). I tried understanding things the "Performance Report" tells me but I do not find any wierd numbers. This is why I need your help.

This is the current configurations I did for MYSQL :

```
max_connections = 250
query_cache_type=1
key_buffer_size=128M
query_cache_size=64M
back_log=100
query_prealloc_size=32K
sort_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
key_cache_age_threshold=3000
key_cache_division_limit=50
memlock=1
max_connect_errors=999999
max_allowed_packet=1M
```

I also changed the somaxcon config of my Ubuntu.
Can someone please help me to hit a higher limit for my MYSQL server ? Because currently my Processors are only at 10% and my RAM at 6GB out of 64 and MYSQL is slowing my website/api down (too much traffic). What is the "perfect" config (I know it doesn't exist).

Oh and I am sure the problem is on that server ; everything runs smoothly if I cut all MYSQL connections and only use my Mongo/Redis ones (each service runs on a different server).

Please help, I am tearing my hair out. Please tell me if you need any screens from MysqlWorkbench.

Comment: I'll currently take your word for the performance of the queries.  What can put a serious brake on things:  connections.  Does your application reuse existing connections, ie. connection pooling?

Comment: What does your storage look like? Does the system start fast and get slower over time? Do you have benchmarks etc?

Comment: Thank you for your answers:
@GerardH.Pille : Yes and No, we only open one connection for every API call (having multiple queries) but we do not pool (is it possible?) by opening a connection for all the API queries. Note that one user will call our API about once every 10 seconds. This means that a user creates a connection every 10 seconds. Is there a way to maintain the connection open in PHP (in this case with SLIM) - i can't find anything about it ?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins : So our benchmarks are a bit sloppy but this is what we can confirm :
1. Senario A (200 Selects per second) : No problem at all
2. Senario B (500 Selects per second) : The first 10 seconds are not an issue but then it slows down. If we maintain the 500 selects per second for 10 minutes, we start getting timeouts
3. Senario C (1000 Selects per second) : It takes a few seconds to crash (actually Apache will go into 503 because of un-ability to handle the MYSQL connections)

Comment: I'm not SLIM (smart in flemish), but IIRC it is sufficient to put "p:" before the hostname to obtain persistent connections.  Anyway, something really simple.  BTW, it looks as if SLIM has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: Yes sorry I made a shortcut ; I use slim that uses Laravel, that uses Eloquent ORM to query Mysql.
Ill have a look at the p:

Comment: You never stated what the issue was - "and mysql seems not to be able to handle it anymore" is not a meaningful diagnostic. You've provided very few runtime metrics from the host and little information about the hardware its running on. This question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that come to mind:

1. What's your active dataset size, what is your `innodb-buffer-pool-size`, and what is the current queue depth of your disks?

The reason being is this comment `Because currently my Processors are only at 10% and my RAM at 6GB out of 64`  - you clearly have more memory you could throw at this, and if you're constantly having to call to disk, that will dramatically impact performance.

2. Rather than trying random recommendations - get data.

We use Percona Monitoring and Management, a free OSS tool to deep dive into our DB performance and diagnose bottlenecks. It goes from query performance and index usage, to hardware utilization. There's plenty of other tools out there but as you said, there's no silver bullet when guessing blind - and we're just guessing blind trying to help. Data will give you that silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things to do to improve your DB performance. I first go to a few things:

- You could try to increase your query_cache_size.
- Create indexes on popular tables

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we just increased the query_cache_size to 128M and it doesnt seem to do much. If you mean creating indexes on the searched columns of our tables, thats already done.

Answer (score 0):

See here  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

> Unlike the mysql extension, mysqli does not provide a separate
>   function for opening persistent connections. To open a persistent
>   connection you must prepend p: to the hostname when connecting.

I'm curious what your benchmarks will show now.

Comment: Hey, I switched to persistant connections but I can't really see any change. I wont really be able to hit my limit before 5pm GMT and therefor wont be able to benchmark before then.
However I thought that my mysql connections would roof as soon as I went in persistant mode ; it doesnt seem as it changes anything though, is it normal ? (I currently had 750 concurrent connections on my website when thaking this screenshot)
See pic : https://imgur.com/a/ukgsaSJ

Comment: If it stays like that, you're OK?

Comment: BTW, "mysql seems not to be able to handle it anymore".  I've re-read your OP.  What is it that gives you that impression?  Is your website slow?

Comment: Well I am happy if it stays at 13-15 but shouldn't be much more? How come it's so low?
Well the response time of the API (apache) is slow. But when I remove all MYSQL connections/queries, the response time is very fast. And even when MYSQL queriying directly, the queries take more time to execute.

Comment: No, it will only grown if the existing connections cannot handle the running queries fast enough. Unless there is a limit on the number of connections somewhere.  How many apache sessions are W (waiting)?  BTW. you have redis, so MySQL isn't bothered with queries for static content, is it?

Comment: Is your website public?  I'd like to see how "slow" it is.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

Lead with # to disable or REMOVE the following
to allow defaults to work for you.

. sort_buffer_size
. read_buffer_size
. read_rnd_buffer_size

additional lines to change or add to my.cnf-ini

```
max_connect_errors=10  # from 999999 to make Hackers/Crackers life miserable
```

. why give them more than 10 chances to guess a password?

These will help.

Comment: @BastianJakobsen  Have you disabled the bad boys in your my.cnf-ini to improve system performance  and limited your hacker exposure to 10 attempts to guess a password?  Thanks

Comment: @BastianJakobsen What is your situation at this time?  If any suggestions helped, upvote/accept if you have enough reputation.  If you are still troubled, describe your current difficulty, please.